# Long time scale correlation

Tags: statistics, correlation

I have some EXTREMELY noisy data (standard deviation a is greater than the mean), but plotting it with a 15 data point running average does well to get a visual indication of the trending.  I want to see if any of my data sets are correlated, but standard correlation gives me very poor results due to the noisiness of the data (and the fact that I care about trends over scales on the order of hundreds of data points).  I'm thinking of maybe just cranking the running average up to a few hundred data points and then running the correlation on those, but something makes me think that there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of a "running average" sounds like you have some kind of time series data.  If so may want to look at cointegration rather than correlation to analyze it.  You can find a good discussion of the differences between correlation and cointegration on SE's Quantitative Finance Beta site.  See:[How are correlation and cointegration related?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/how-are-correlation-and-cointegration-related)

Not original to me, but the simple comparative description in the mentioned post that best captures the difference for me came from the contributor, isomorphismes:

> - Correlation is a property of collections of observations.
> - Cointegration is a property of time series.
>
> The important difference is that temporal observations have one
>   neighbour to their left and one to their right. Collections are like a
>   set — no implicit "neighbour" relationships.
>
> Moving average is an inappropriate statistic to apply to lab
>   experiments or phone survey data. It is appropriate in the analysis of
>   time series.

and a comment:

> Interesting point to make. If we are comparing two time series,
>   correlation tell us something about the complete time series as a
>   whole, whereas cointegration tells us something about the individual
>   matching points.

from user, Gravitas.

If you still want to stay with correlation consider applying it to the log of the differences at each time step.